# Bootstrap 4: Difference between text-center and justify-content-center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Both text-center and justify-content-center seem to be doing much the same thing - centering text. But what's the difference?

Comment: Can you show the code? I can't find any "justify-text-center" class in the bootstrap documentation, are you sure it's called that?

Comment: Did you mean 'justify-content-center' instead of  'justify-text-center'? there is no sush thing as  justify-text-center

Comment: I edited my question. I meant justify-content-center.

Comment: `justify-content-center` is meant for centering the contents of grid cells in Bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment `text-center` is for simple text alignment within blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4 doesn't support for `justify-text-center`.

Source: [Text](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/)

---

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p class="text-justify">Ambitioni dedisse scripsisse iudicaretur. Cras mattis iudicium purus sit amet fermentum. Donec sed odio operae, eu vulputate felis rhoncus. Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi. At nos hinc posthac, sitientis piros Afros. Petierunt uti sibi concilium totius Galliae in diem certam indicere. Cras mattis iudicium purus sit amet fermentum.</p>

<p class="text-center">Center aligned text on all viewport sizes.</p>
```

---

> I meant, justify-content-center

The difference is: `justify-content-*` is used to change the alignment of `flex` items.

If the div doesn't have property `display: flex`. It doesn't seem to work. While `text-center` doesn't require property `display: flex`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div style="background-color: red;">Item 1</div>
  <div style="background-color: yellow;">Item 2</div>
  <div style="background-color: blue;">Item 3</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="justify-content-center">
  <div style="background-color: red;">Item 1</div>
  <div style="background-color: yellow;">Item 2</div>
  <div style="background-color: blue;">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I meant, justify-content-center. Can you clarify the difference between it and text-center

Comment: @Daud I've updated the answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 2):

#### text-center

> The text-align CSS property specifies the horizontal alignment of an inline or table-cell box.This means it works like vertical-align but in the horizontal direction. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

`text-center` aligns  **inline** and **table-cell** element in the center of the element you use it for. It does not change the alignment of **block** elements.

---

#### justify-content-center

> The items are packed flush to each other toward the center of the alignment container along the main axis.

```css
.justify-content-center {
  -ms-flex-pack: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
}
```

In order for this to work, you need to use `d-flex` also. It aligns all the content of the element(**inline**, **block**,and **flex**) you use it for in the center of the element.  By default, the content of the element is centered horizontally should you have not changed the `flex-direction` of the element.

---

*You may find these links useful.*

- [Inline Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)
- [Block Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)
- [Flexible Box Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)